# SSRS Report suddenly hanging

Tags: reporting-services

Have an SSRS I created in VS 2008.  SQL server = 2008r2, authenticated login with my domain credentials.

The report I have has about 12 or so TableX controls on it with various queries to produce a summary report of activity.

Everything was fine when I left yesterday, however, when I came in this morning, the report just hangs when I click "preview" (or run the report in debugger).  All I see is "report is being generated" and then I have to go into task manager and kill devenv.exe to recover from it.

Inside the report designer I've ran each query individually to verify that there are no "long running" queries and there arent.  Each take about a second to return results.  Other reports in the package run fine, just this one is an issue.

Is there someplace I can look or do I have to start deleting TableX's one by one to find the culprit (if thats even the problem).

Thanks

Frank

Comment: More than once either (a) restarting VStudio or (b) manually removing .data files has made problems I was having with SSRS disappear.

Comment: Additionally there's [ExecutionLog2](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/robertbruckner/archive/2009/01/05/executionlog2-view.aspx) but that's only available if you run it on the server. Are you able to deploy the report as is, and see if it also "hangs" on the server?

Comment: Restarted VStudio no joy, delete .data files, no joy, no access to ExecutionLog2 as the SQL server is on a box I dont have access to, nor do we have a "server" per say because it's not a production report...it's supposed to be a stop gap report until the production report is completed...which will not be an SSRS report.  Any other thoughts?

Comment: It's probably fastest then if you narrow it down to the offending tablix first, by process of elimination. The only other things I can think of will probably be less practical (e.g. run it on a different PC, a backup of the DB from a while ago, review the RDL code for problems, etc).

Comment: Yah, so one by one elimination (or addition, going to create a new report and re-add them one by one.  It has to be a query because if I put in bogus params, the report displays ....0's but it does at lest display....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Time to put my comments into an answer (even though you've already tried some of 'em). You ask for methods to find out which part of a report is tripping up execution, here's my 2 cts.

First things you can try when you're stuck:

- **Restart Visual Studio** (the good 'ole "have you tried turning it off and on again?")
- **Remove the .data files** to force a refresh of the data being queried

If you want to dive a little deeper and have access to a true reportserver:

- Deploy to a reporting server, and **check [the execution log](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/robertbruckner/archive/2009/01/05/executionlog2-view.aspx)**

Some additional things that may help:

- **running the queries seperately** in Visual Studio and/or in SSMS, preferably with the same parameter values as the ones tripping up the report (mentioning this for completeness, but the question already states this didn't resolve anything)
- try to **run** the report **against a recent backup of the database** (if available), a recent change or increase in data may be the cause of your troubles
- **Review the RDL code**, specifically the queries, and look for trouble :)
- Include a `TOP 10` or something similar in all your queries to find out which one is causing trouble.

Failing all that I think your best option is the one you already mention: find the offending tablix and query by process of elimination.

As a final thought, the two things that caused 99% of our performance problems in SSRS:

1. Pivoting (so: tablix with dynamic columns) with lots of data and/or funky formatting/layouting expressions.
2. Overuse of subreports.

Hope this was helpful to you or any future visitor. *If not be sure to answer your own question here and tell us how you solved things in the end.*

Comment: Restarted - Nothing Changed
Delete .data files - Nothing Changed
Dont have access to a report server to check the execution log (was just looking at the report in preview tab of designer)
Ran each query individually, all ran fine w/out significant load times.
No pivots or subreports.

Basically what I've done is just create a blank report, and copied over the tablix and dataset queries over and everything is ok now....until next time I guess.  

Thanks for the help

Frank

Answer (score 3):

While this question is years old, I found it when trying to figure out my own problem. Here's my solution, just in case it helps anyone else:

**Close any instance of Server Management Studio connected to the database in question.**

In my case, I had SSMS open and connected to the database server from another computer and had been testing some long-running stored procedures on the same database that my reports were trying to connect to.  There must have been some lingering connection(s) that caused it to not respond, as after having the problem in SSRS I started getting timeouts for very simple queries in SSMS as well.

Once I closed SSMS and waited a moment my reports ran fine in SSRS.

Answer (score 1):

For me, closing SSMS, Restarting VS did not work. I had an orphaned transaction that SQL Server did not cleanup. Simply execute the following if none of the above works and what worked for me may solve your SSRS crash issue:

```
IF(SELECT @@TRANCOUNT) > 0
  COMMIT TRANSACTION
```